# Following up on an anonymous question

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

I have asked a question here recently (anonymously - due to a sensitive matter), but I now can't do anything with it, since I don't actually have any reputation on the site (I can't edit the question, or comment on it to clarify).

Is there anything I can do about this?

Comment: Basically, no, other than using the alias account enough to gain those privileges or using it to ask here if someone bcould edit for you... which of course is now potentially compromised. The system is designed for participation, not just as an oracle.

Comment: What is it that you want to do with this question? Some folks without sufficient rep ask for help in a comment to their own question or in chat. If you can still be anonymous, you could ask here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your other account would need to earn some reputation to gain those privileges.  It's ok to have multiple accounts, but you have to be careful that they don't interact -- they can't vote for each other, give bounties to each other, both vote on the same posts or comments, or anything else that you couldn't do with just one account.

I don't understand why you can't edit or comment on your own post, though.  You have to be logged in as that user (I recommend an incognito window for this), but users can always edit and comment on their own posts.

If you didn't register the account and have lost access to it, though, there might not be much that can be done.  Sorry about that.

Answer (score 3):

You can suggest anonymous edits even without being a logged in user.

If you do this, you should indicate in the reason something clarifying this is the case - I would strongly encourage you to do this if you choose to edit your question in this fashion.

Anonymous edits go into the suggested edit review queue, which is why you should try to clarify in your edit reason why/what you are doing, so that people do not automatically reject it for changing the intent too much.

Comment: As Ben has now asked this meta question from his main account, an anonymous suggested edit saying "this is my question really" is pretty much going to tie Ben to the question he wanted to keep anonymous...